# Mocking postForObject using PowerMockito throws error

Tags: resttemplate, powermockito

I'm trying to mock RestTemplates postForObject method using PowerMockito.

```
PowerMockito.when(mockRestTemplate, "postForObject", 
            Mockito.eq(URI.class), Mockito.eq(Object.class), Mockito.eq(Class.class))
        .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

This is throwing a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'responseType' must not be null
```

I gather it needs to meet a notNull constraint on the postForObject's method's responseType parameter. But I am not able to figure out how to mention this.

```
public <T> T postForObject(URI url, @Nullable Object request, Class<T> responseType)
```

Comment: for the test what is the intended/expected type you are trying to return?

Comment: It is a object with a corresponding model that jackson will parse for me. I tried mentioning the actual Object.class in the last parameter. Still end up with the same error